# Python regex, multiline search with start of line

Tags: python, regex

I have a block of text as shown below.

```
import re

one = """
ASDFABC
ABC
ABC
ABC
ASDF
ASDF
ASDF
ASDFABC"""

two = """\
ABC
ABC
ABC

ASDF
ASDF
ASDF
ASDFABC"""
```

I am searching for a way replace the whole block **starting** from ABC replaced by one single "TEST". for example, variable one should result in,

```
"""
ASDFABC
TEST
ASDF
ASDF
ASDF
ASDFABC"""
```

As a side note, ABC not starting from the beginning of the line could be anywhere as shown in first and last line in "one" and those should be ignored. Also as shown in "two" ABC is not necessarily followed by "\n"

How could this be done ?

**Attempts made so far.**

```
>>> re.findall(r"(?:\nABC.*)+", one)
['\nABC\nABC\nABC']

>>> re.findall(r"(?:\nABC.*)+", two)
['\nABC\nABC']

>>> re.findall(r"(?:\nABC.*)+", two, re.M)
['\nABC\nABC']

>>> re.findall(r"(?:\nABC.*)+", two, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
['\nABC\nABC\n\nASDF\nASDF\nASDF\nASDFABC']

>>> re.findall(r"(?:^ABC.*)+", two, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
['ABC\nABC\nABC\n\nASDF\nASDF\nASDF\nASDFABC']

>>> re.findall(r"(?:^ABC.*)+", two, re.MULTILINE)
['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC']

>>> re.findall(r"(?:\n*ABC.*)+", two, re.MULTILINE)
['ABC\nABC\nABC', 'ABC']
```

Comment: Why `re.findall`, if you need to replace? Try `re.sub(r'^ABC(?:\n.+)*', 'TEST', text, flags=re.M)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oI7PRT/1).

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't work as it just blindly follows anything after ABC regardless of what the next line is. For example, "ABC\nABC\nDEF" would capture the full string. I just used findall to see the capture before sub :)

Comment: So, you want `^ABC(?:\nABC)*$`? Like  [here](https://regex101.com/r/oI7PRT/2)? `re.sub(r'^ABC(?:\nABC)*$', 'TEST', text, flags=re.M)`

Comment: Exactly. This worked. Thanks heaps. if you like, please make it an answer :)

Comment: When you say "block of text" I assume the first line is `'import re\n'` and the last line is `'ASDFABC"""\n'`. If that's not what you mean you need to change your wording or your example. Perhaps you simply mean two strings, the first being, `"ASDFABC\nABC\nABC\nABC\nASDF\nASDF\nASDF\nASDFABC"`. Nor is `"replace the whole block starting from ABC"` clear. Presumably you mean "all contiguous lines `"ABC\n"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'^ABC(?:\nABC)*$', 'TEST', text, flags=re.M)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oI7PRT/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of a line (due to `re.M`)
- `ABC` - a fixed string
- `(?:\nABC)*` - zero or more repetitions of an LF char and `ABC` string
- `$` - end of a line.

Note that `flags=re.M` needs to be used with `flags=` since the next positional attribute in [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) after the input string is a *count* attribute.